# Boundary conditions for equation of motion of a chain under small vertical motion of its support

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, boundary-conditions, differential-equations

I would like to find the boundary conditions for the of motion of a chain under small vertical motion of its support endpoint. I also assume displacement of the chain in the vertical $y$ direction is much smaller than the chain length.

The mass per unit length of the chain is $\rho$, $g$ is the gravity acceleration, the support point moves with a motion described by $Y(t)$, $\hat{x},\hat{y}$ are the unit vectors in the $x,y$ directions, $u(y,t)$ is the transverse displacement. The length of the chain is $L$.

When at rest the chain support point lies at position $x=0,y=L$ with the chain lying straight down along the $y$ axis and its endpoint at position $x=0, y=0$.

First lets use Newton's 2nd law to get the equation of motion of the chain.

In a non inertial frame moving with the acceleration $\ddot{Y}$ of the support and since the displacement of the chain in the vertical $y$ direction is negligible, the vertical equation of motion is basically the equilibrium of the tension force and the gravity force so we get

$$\boldsymbol{T(y)}.\hat{y}=\rho y[g-\ddot{Y}]$$

If $\theta$ is the angle between $\boldsymbol{T}$ and $\hat{y}$ this equation is equivalent to

$$|T|\cos\theta=\rho y[g-\ddot{Y}]$$

In the horizontal $x$ direction

$$[\boldsymbol{T(y+\Delta y)}-\boldsymbol{T(y)}].\hat{x}=\rho\Delta y\frac{\partial^{2}u}{\partial t^{2}}$$

Taking the limit $\Delta y\rightarrow 0$ leads to

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial y}[\boldsymbol{T(y)}.\hat{x}]\equiv \frac{\partial}{\partial y}[|T(y)|\sin\theta]\equiv \frac{\partial}{\partial y}[\rho y(g-\ddot{Y})\tan\theta]=\rho y\frac{\partial^{2}u}{\partial t^{2}}$$

Since $\tan\theta=\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$ we finally get the equation (assuming $\rho=constant$)

$$[g-\ddot{Y}]\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left[y\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right]=y\frac{\partial^{2}u}{\partial t^{2}}$$

The question I have is what are the boundary conditions under which I should solve this equation? If the support were fixed ($Y=0$) then I could do $u(y=L,t)=0$ at the support and I would need one more condition as well (which probably would be at the free end of the chain but is not clear to me what it would be). Given that the support moves with $Y(t)$ what are the 2 boundary conditions in this case?